# Update Ranking Javascript SetInterval Only Works the First Execution

Tags: javascript, pusher

This is for a ranking leaderboard update. It changes the values and temporarily the color. It works perfect the first time the value is changed, but barely noticeable the second and thereafter executions.

```
channel.bind('amount_update', function(data) {
  document.getElementById('active-tokens-' + data.owner).innerHTML = data.active_tokens;
  document.getElementById('active-capital-' + data.owner).innerHTML = '$' + (data.active_tokens*.9).toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById('historical-tokens-' + data.owner).innerHTML = data.historical_tokens;
  document.getElementById('ranking-' + data.owner).innerHTML = (data.ranking).toFixed(2);

  function Update() {
    document.getElementById('active-tokens-' + data.owner).style.color = "#23cc96";
    document.getElementById('active-capital-' + data.owner).style.color = "#23cc96";
    document.getElementById('historical-tokens-' + data.owner).style.color = "#23cc96";
  }

  Update();
  function OriginalColor(){
    document.getElementById('active-tokens-' + data.owner).style.color = "grey";
    document.getElementById('active-capital-' + data.owner).style.color = "grey";
    document.getElementById('historical-tokens-' + data.owner).style.color = "grey";
  }
  c = setInterval(OriginalColor, 2000);
});
```

Comment: Why do call OriginalColor in the setInterval.  It only set the color as grey, so no change.

Comment: @DominiqueFortin I call Update which changes the color and then call Original Color to change the color back to grey after 2 seconds. I thought this would be an appropriate solution for creating a timer, almost inversely.

Comment: Could you make small code snippet to see what you mean?

Comment: @DominiqueFortin I included it in the question above.

Comment: A Code snippet is like what you can see on JSFiddle.  This make a working code that can be executed.  When you edit, click on the `[<>]` button to make one. If add some HTML with the right IDs, I could test your problem with you.

Comment: @DominiqueFortin Hey, just solved my own problem. Also, thanks for that info, I am new to SO. Anyways, SetTimeout was switched to SetInterval. clearInterval() was ending my action before it had time to fully carry out. Thanks for the help.